# Does the Angular 2 Injector give you a 'new' instantiation every time?

Tags: angular

In a unit test I am calling the injector and spying on the http object like this...

```
  beforeEach(async(inject([MyRepository, MockBackend, Http],(myRepository: MyRepository, backend: MockBackend, http : Http) => {

   spyOn(http,'get').and.callThrough();

    backend.connections.subscribe((conn: MockConnection) => {
      const options: ResponseOptions = new ResponseOptions({body: '[{"name":"chris"},{"name":"dave"}]'});
      conn.mockRespond(new Response(options));
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

  })));
```

But when I refactor the `spyOn` funcion into a helper method like this...

```
class myTestHelper{
  public static spyOnHttp(): void{
    inject([Http],(http : Http) => {
      spyOn(http, 'get').and.callThrough();
    });
  }
}
```

And then call my new code from my test setup (instead of the spyOn directly) I get the following error...

`Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`

It's like using a new inject function is returning a different http object. But I thought they would be the same? If they aren't how does angular know which one to use if a new one is created every time the injector is used?

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 DI maintains a single instance per provider.

If you provide some service on a component, each instance of this component will get its own service instance.
All it's children will get the same service instance as well, except when one of the children also has a provider for this service.

If you provide a service in `@NgModule()`, then they are hoisted on the DI root scope and single instances are shared with the whole application (again as long as not a component has its own provider for the same token).

When several modules provide the same service, still only a single instance is maintained by DI because with multiple providers for the same token for the ones added later override the ones previously added.

Lazy loaded modules get their own scope where providers in `@NgModule()` are hoisted.

DI starts looking by the component the requests a dependency and looks upwords towards the root scope for a provider for this dependency and returns the serv ice instance of the first provider it finds.

A token can be the type (class) of a service, a string or an `OpaqueToken`.

In the short form `providers: [SomeService]` is the same as `providers: [{provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService}]` and the type is used as token (or key) (`provide: SomeService`) and also as value (`useClass: SomeService`)

Comment: So in that case surely I would have access to the same 'http' argument regardless of where I call it since I am only setting up one component in my test?

Comment: If you reuse the same component instance and only provide `Http` in that component, you should get the same instance. However, `Http` is stateless and I don't know what you mean with "have access to the same 'http' argument. `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)` creates a new component instance for each test, therefore each test gets a different `Http` instance.